# Переключение фона страницы или дива

Tags: css3, jquery, javascript, css

Не могу реализовать переключение фона страницы при наведение на ссылку. Есть меню и необходимо чтобы при наведении на его элементы, менялся фон страницы. Кто сталкивался с такой реализацией?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    font-size: 1em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0 0 7px #000000;
    color: #FFF;
    background: url(http://cred-fin.ru/_ph/1/2/724349401.jpg) 0 0 repeat;
}
.green-bg {
    background-image: url(http://img.pixasa.net/static/3/a/2/3a202aa5-0c13-4214-ab53-ddc39ef80cef.jpg);
    background-color: #060;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var _body = $('body');
$('span').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        _body.toggleClass('green-bg');
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        _body.toggleClass('green-bg');
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<span>Hover me</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Для будущих поколений, рабочий вариант напрямую с body
<a href="#" onmouseover="body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(images/01.jpg)';">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оберните код в document ready или переставьте скрипт в конец документа. 
В коде нет подключения jQuery. Это нужно сделать до перед основным скриптом.

Comment: Спасибо Deonis и вам за помощь. Помогло.

Comment: Кстати нашел еще один вариант <a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('pic').src='pics/48.gif';">зеленый</a> но параметр передается только картинки или bgcolor? как его можно передавать bgimage?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sxrwt/

Answer (score 0):

примерно [так](http://jsfiddle.net/4jB2T/)

Comment: при такой реализации у меня не получается, дело в том что если в CSS листе изначально указан стартовый фон, то в дальнейшем скрипт не работает.

Comment: А [такой вариант][1]?

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/4W2S5/1/

Comment: аналогично не работает, на фоне картинка и заменяется другой картинкой

Comment: Вот вам с [другой картинкой][1]. Всё работает, но вполне возможно, что второй фон подгрузиться не сразу, но для этого есть свои способы решения.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/4W2S5/3/

Comment: в вопросе прицепил пример кода. что не так? не работает

Comment: Оберните код в конструкцию DOM-Ready

    $(document).ready(function(){
         // тут код
    });
    // или сокращенная форма
    $(function(){
         // тут код
    });